# Skype 4.0 still looks like 2.2 beta

Tags: themes, fonts, skype

I've just installed skype 4.0 for my Ubuntu 12.4LTS and the font and setup of it still looks like the older ersion 2.2 beta. I've tryed reinstalling it, and rebooting my computer but it doesn't help. I know that it's suppose to look differently according to screenshots of other people using it.

Comment: Check the "About Skype" from the menu, and it will tell you what version is running.

Comment: it says 4.0.0.7 but still looks like 2.2 beta

Comment: have you purged your old skype install first before installing the deb package?

Comment: purged? you mean uninstalled

Comment: yes of cource i did

Comment: purged means not only uninstalling, but getting rid of the configuration files, which can sometimes have an effect.  Personally, I'm pretty happy with the way 2.2 looks, and sometimes I hate it when there is a new version and I have to relearn how to use it.  But then, all I use it for is messaging and video calls.

Comment: yes i purge removed it with terminal, uninstalled with software center, deleted .skype file in /home and even did search for ANY possible left files taht can leave traces of skype
i've tried pretty much everything i could, but still no good result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to upgrade to 4.0 from the previous 2.2 beta version:

from: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1695589

1) make sure the old version is purged, and that old config files are moved to a backup folder (in case you want to restore them later if there's a problem)

`sudo apt-get autoremove --purge skype`

`mv ~/.Skype ~/.Skype.bak`

2) download the 4.0 deb from the skype website (http://www.skype.com/intl/fr/get-skype/on-your-computer/linux/) and install from commandline:

e.g., `sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/skype-ubuntu_4.0.0.7-1_amd64.deb`

this will fail with an error. that's ok! we have to run the following command to fix dependencies:

`sudo apt-get install -f`

now install again:

`sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/skype-ubuntu_4.0.0.7-1_amd64.deb`

Comment: no, check again

Comment: http://skype.com/intl/en-us/get-skype/on-your-computer/linux/

Comment: 4.0 came out 50 minutes ago

Comment: OK Sorry For that try this :
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1695589

Comment: http://blogs.skype.com/linux/2012/06/skype_40_for_linux.html

Comment: also i noticed that when i install this version of skype, the launchbar stops hiding, and in the apperiance settings it says taht it is set to autohide, but yet doesn't hide

Comment: @AminosAmigos hope you don't mind that I edited your answer to include all the info from the comments

Comment: I'll note that it looks like there are still elements of 2.2b, so I'm sure there's a bit missing from this solution. For instance, I don't get the nice unity dock and messaging menu integration I've seen in screenshots.

Comment: can you send me a link of a screenshot of what it should look like?

Comment: http://www.webupd8.org/2012/06/skype-40-for-linux-available-for.html

Comment: @amc It's more than Ok I got more reputation thanks To you:)

Comment: @NickyBailuc that happened to me too :/ But after rebooting it worked (used the ubuntu tweak tool)