# No application icon in Unity bar with Skype 4.0

Tags: unity, indicator, skype

After installing Skype 4.0 on Ubuntu Precise, I see its indicator in top bar, but there is no running application icon on the left, thus I can't focus into it and pin to the Launcher.

I had 2.2 version before, but purged it as described in [Skype 4.0 still looks like 2.2 beta](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150864/skype-4-0-still-looks-like-2-2-beta/150868#150868), so I believe this can be considered clean install.

Related question is whether it's possible to have overlay with new/unread messages in the unity launcher icon similar to indicator?

Comment: Try to start a chat from the menu that opens clicking the icon in unity panel. Doing this, I see the icon in the launcher.

Comment: There was no icon at all, but appeared after I rebooted. In combination with skype-wrapper it works as expected.

Answer (score 12):

You have to install [sni-qt](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/sni-qt) [image: Install sni-qt] package:

If your Ubuntu is 32 bits:

```
sudo apt-get install sni-qt
```

Or, if you are using 64 bits:

```
sudo apt-get install sni-qt:i386
```

I'm not sure if you need to logout / login afterwards, but Skype will then appear together with other indicators.

Comment: This solves the problem even in Gnome fallback mode (non-Unity).

Answer (score 2):

Consider the missing launcher a benefit and install [skype-wrapper](https://launchpad.net/~skype-wrapper/+archive/ppa), which integrates Skype nicely into Unity:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:skype-wrapper/ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install skype-wrapper
```

See this article for further details: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/05/skype-wrapper-adds-call-actions-notification-fixes-ubuntu-12-04-support

Answer (score 2):

I have equal behavior with skype icon. But, after using "apt-get install" from command line to install skype, this problem was resolved.

You should try to install skype using "apt-get install", if it's not that.

More over, this installation method is recomended instead of skype website.

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install skype
```

I've found it here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Skype

Answer (score 1):

It's actually back to what it used to be (in early versions of Ubuntu), so you need to 'whitelist' the notification icon.

Take a look at http://www.webupd8.org/2011/04/how-to-re-enable-notification-area.html (or google 'skype whitelist ubuntu'.